# Question about the efficiency of DomDocument

Tags: php, mysql, insert, performance, domdocument

Note: This is something I'm working on as an exercise.

I have a php program which modifies a html document using DomDocument; by inserting, deleting, or editing, an element by ID. When the program is finished, it outputs the document for users to view.

The SQL table containing the values inserted is only sorted/used to provide the element that should be before the new element. e.g. based on the specified column value, it finds the element that is right before the new element, and insert the new element after it.

Basically what I'm asking is how efficient this approach compared to having all the elements stored in the database and then recreating the (various) html files every single time.

Side question: I want to save the 'history' of each element. Should I make a new table for each specific element (e.g. a234-history) or is there a better way of going about this?

EDIT:

Code Snippet:

*Warning; Spaghetti code ahead.*

```
    if ($sortby=='newest')
        $query2=mysql_query("SELECT comnum FROM comments WHERE replynum='$x' AND newest <  '$new' ORDER BY newest DESC LIMIT 1");
    else
       $query2=mysql_query("SELECT comnum FROM comments WHERE replynum='$x' AND popularity <  '$random' ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 1");
    $query1= mysql_fetch_object($query2);
    $query=$query1->comnum;
    echo $query;
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($sortby.".html"));
    $ap=$doc->createElement('span', "<p class='comm'><b>".$_POST['poster']."</b><span class='reply'> Popularity: ".$random." Post Number:".$data."<a href='javascript:reply(".$data.")'>Reply</a></span><br/>".$_POST['comments']."</p><div class='comm1' id='".$data."'></div>");
    $ap->setAttribute('id',$data.'a');
    if ($query!=false) {
       $query.='a';
       $doc->getElementById($x)->insertBefore($ap, $doc->getElementById($query));
        echo $x;
    }
    else {
         $doc->getElementById($x)->appendChild($ap);
        }
    mysql_close($don);
    $we= $doc->saveHTML();
    $we = preg_replace("/<!DOCTYPE [^>]+>/",'',$we);
    $we = str_replace('<html><body>', '', $we);
    $we = str_replace('</body></html>', '', $we);
    file_put_contents($sortby.".html",htmlspecialchars_decode($we));
    if ($_POST['order']==$sortby)
        echo htmlspecialchars_decode($we);
```

Table Structure:

Field           Type
comnum          int(255)
username    varchar(255)
comment         text
replynum    int(255)
popularity  int(255)
newest          int(255)

No specified encoding.

Comment: can you please post some php code and also the table structure you've got so far?

Comment: To me it looks like your code is doing something like templating. It seems crazy to do all this with DOM manipulation when just pumping HTML at the browser would achieve the same thing, but I'm guessing that's why it's an exercise!

As for saving history, you really want to avoid doing schema changes, which includes table creation, so I'd say you should probably keep old versions either in the same table (and select latest for display), or break out all but the latest into a separate table (assuming that looking at history will be a relatively rare thing).

Comment: @Synchro
The reason why I'm using DOM manipulation is so that the user doesn't have to do so on their end. I could output all the comments with the attached metadata and have the javascript sort through it, but I don't know how much more efficient that would be than serverside. You raise an interesting question, and I hope someone has a response to this.

As for saving history, yes I was thinking having a seperate table for each comment's old text.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you are basically managing a cache of HTML documents, which are being changed as database information is changed.
The goal of this is trying to achieve that the document is already there for the user, and does not need to be re-created for them.

If the written above is correct, whether or not it is an efficient approach depends on the ratio of reads and writes for your data.
If there are 1000 visits for each update, then your method is probably more efficient than creating a document for each visit.

To find out about the exact ratio of read/write you need to achieve for it to be considered efficient, you will have to run tests.

Comment: Yep. You basically wrote what I had in mind, but as you said, I have to test it out.

I'm curious to  seehow forum engines, reddit, disqus etc, manage their comment/threading systems in regards to my approach . I suppose I can dive in to some installations some others time to answer that question however.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you could also serve statically cached html, and use script localization in combination with JSViews/JSRender/Static to deliver your variables using a restful api.